# How to add an item to a listview on a button click event?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am coding in Android Studio and having some trouble. I have a button and a listview. When the button is clicked it should add a hardcoded String to the arraylist.

```
List participants;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initParticipants();

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, participants);
    ListView participantList = findViewById(R.id.participantList);
    participantList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}

public void changeJoinState(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if(checked) {

        participants.add("example");

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Joined event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }

}

void initParticipants() {
    participants = new ArrayList<String>();
    participants.add("Creator");
}
```

Comment: what is the issue here?? you haven't told anything about that

Comment: The issue is that I am having trouble adding the String to my Arraylist called "Participants", when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the list you should call notifyDataSetChanged to see the updated UI. Make the ListView variable at class level. Also call notifyDataSetChanged after adding string to list.

```
participants.add("example");
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Results in the following error " cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged() ". Do you know the solutions for this too?

Comment: @ZakiHussain change type of ListAdapter to ArrayAdapter

Comment: @ZakiHussain also call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter object

Comment: it does not provide me with any error messages now, but the app just crashes when I click the button.

Comment: This worked after I made the ArrayAdapter global. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use notifyDataSetChanged()

```
void initParticipants() {
   participants = new ArrayList<String>();
   participants.add("Creator");
   participants.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change if conditional block code with below code

```
 if(checked) {

    participants.add("example");
     participantList.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Joined event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

}
```

**Whenever there is a change in a list, adapter needs to be notified via notifyDataSetChanged() method**

Comment: This results in the following error " cannot resolve symbol 'participantList' "

Comment: Make ListView participantList as a global reference means that take piece of code out of oncreate method and initialze in onCreate

Comment: in current situation your listview reference is a local variable reference you need to make that global to access outside onCreate mehod. Hope you get my point

Comment: I think I got your point, but this results in the following error " cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged() ". Do you know the solutions for this too?